# What does pointer in struct mean

Tags: c, pointers, struct, syntax, c-preprocessor

I have read the related question but I couldn't understand it; what does it mean when we have this:

```
struct address {
# define N (4) 
struct address *nb[N]; } *site;
```

What does it mean by putting `#define N (4)` in `struct` what's the difference if it was outside `struct` and I don't understand what `struct address *nb[N];` does. Would you please explain it clearly and completely exactly what does a pointer in structure mean; I can't digest it at all.

Comment: Do you really have a `;` there?

Comment: I know " Pointers are used to store the address of memory location" please please answer to this question in really simple way I found some answer to other questions confusing.

Comment: You really need to know something about C before working with the language. Read a book or do some tutorials first.

Comment: The `#define` part can be anywhere before the struct declaration.  You do need to get rid of the `;` though.  Why not just `#define N 4`?

Comment: `struct address *nb[N];` is an array of `struct address` pointers.

Comment: you mean after (4), no I made a mistake

Comment: I know it's an array of [struct address] pointer bout I don't know what exactly do

Comment: With the `;` in define in won't even compile. Did you try it?

Comment: I have read some books but some problem remained and I couldn't find struct with array in any of them. could you introduce me complete ones

Comment: I told you it was my type mistake here I didn't have any ";" over there

Comment: It is best practice to write `#define N 4` at the top of the file, so that all the code below can see it. As far as books, I really recommend to you a quick google search: literally typing in "C language using arrays" brought up lots of links and tutorials, and all free. That way when you bring a question to ask, you'll have a bit better understanding of peoples' replies.

Comment: @moshtagh: Just think of it as a struct that contains 4 addresses because that's all pointers are anyways.  Once you dereference one those pointers you will get another struct that contains 4 addresses, etc.

Comment: @moshtagh: A pointer is just a variable that contains an address and that is it.  Pointers don't contain any value, just an address to data.

Comment: thanks ruffles I wish the best for you

Answer (score 2):

I think what's happened is the person who wrote that code didn't understand how preprocessor macros work.

The answer to your question is that there is no difference between defining it inside the struct versus outside the struct, apart from that defining it outside the struct is better coding style.

By the way, just about every single part of that `#define` is incorrect or obtuse.  It should read:

```
#define N 4
```

As for your other question about the pointer in the structure, the `nb` element is simply an array of pointers to the same structure.

It's not clear how this would be useful, because the structure does not contain any other elements, making it pointless for something like a tree.  My guess is that it is being used for some custom memory manager.

Comment: There is a difference where to define a macro constant. because you can append its definition with other macro instruction #undef. So the scope of the constant can be limited by the structure definition.

Comment: what happened after all, there is difference or not?

Comment: @moshtagh Well, that point was valid but only if the structure had a corresponding `#undef N` before the end.  Again it's a style thing.  My argument is that if you're not going to do that, then don't define macros inside a block (even though there is no actual difference).  Doing so fools the casual eye into thinking that the value is only valid within that scope.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, first change

```
 # define N (4);
```

to

```
 # define N (4)
```

Then, to say, the `#define` works like a *textual* replacement. So, after preprocessing, your code looks like

```
struct address 
{
   struct address *nb[4]; 
} *site;
```

> *what's difference if it was outside struct*

Nothing, it's the same.

> *what struct address *nb[N]; does*

Well, it *does* nothing, it *means*, `nb` is a member of `struct address`, and of type of an array of 4 pointers to `struct address`.

Answer (score 1):

It could be rewritten as:

```
struct address {
    struct address *nb1;
    struct address *nb2;
    struct address *nb3;
    struct address *nb4;
} *site;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're right, but then the whole purpose of array is defeated. Just saying. :-) And my personal opinion, I hate those `1`, `2`s popping up in variable names.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I know that, I was just rewriting to demonstrate to the OP for simplicity.

Comment: He's asking about `struct address *nb[N];` for crying out loud!

Comment: no, it's not the same. You can't address those separate variables with an index like with arrays

Comment: When did I say it was the same?  I was just trying to lay out the variables to the OP for simplicity.